# Will weekly paychecks be reduced after taking FMLA leave?

Tags: united-states, salary, paycheck, maternity-leave

My wife works as a US public school teacher.

She took several months off for maternity leave. Because she only had a month of paid sick leave accumulated, 6 weeks went unpaid. The workplace simply stopped giving her paychecks until she returned. We assumed that would be the only reductions to salary.

But looking over the finances, I find after she returned from maternity leave, they also reduced subsequent paychecks by 8% (before taxes). Since maternity leave until now, all paychecks were reduced by this 8%, even though she's been back, working full time.

Is that normal pay is taken out in several paychecks, then also taken out as a percent of further paychecks for the rest of the year?

Comment: What reason did the school district provide for this drop in pay?

Answer (score 4):

Talk to the teachers union. They will understand the local/state law, and the contract provisions.

Each pay stub should have an explanation for every item on the stub. If you don't see what changed or you don't understand what changed, ask.

Things that might have changed:

- Insurance
- The loss of extra pay related to coaching, or running a club.